# Can I add google adsense code between the <head> and </head> tags of EJS files?

Tags: ejs, adsense

I have applied for Google AdSense for my website [gulzari.in](https://gulzari.in). I added the AdSense code between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags of .ejs file. After two weeks, I am getting the error "Connect your site to AdSense" even though I added the AdSense code between `<head>` and `</head>` tags of .ejs file.
I created the website using node js, express, MongoDB, .ejs, CSS and javascript.
Please help me! Where I am going wrong? Can I add Google Adsense code between the `<head>` and `</head>` in the .ejs file (https://ejs.co/) file? If not, what should I do to connect AdSense to my website created using nodejs, express, MongoDB, EJS, CSS and Javascript?